# Azure App Service, docker container deployment, unable to pass cap-add=NET_ADMIN property during docker run

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile, azure-web-app-service

I was doing single container deployment in the azure app service. As my container needs to be run in the `NET_ADMIN` mode, i had to pass `cap-add=NET_ADMIN` during the docker run, something like this

`docker run -e cap-add=NET_ADMIN -p 8080:8080 my_image:v1`

In azure app service we have to pass the runtime arguments in the configurations.

But it is a known issue that we can't pass any key with `- (hiphen)` from configurations.

So i am unable run my container in the `NET_ADMIN` mode.

Is there any work around, so that i will be able to run with `NET_ADMIN` mode in azure app service?

`Base image : alpine 4.1.4`

PS: My requirement needs me to run a single container and not with docker-compose

Comment: Does the image create yourself and the environment variable needed as you set? If yes, could you set the environment variable without `- (hiphen)` when you create the image?

Comment: No, setting the key name is not in my hands. ```cap-add``` is a standard keyword to add linux capabilities during docker run time

Comment: Unfortunately, Azure Web app does not support the `- (hiphen)` currently for the environment variables.